# Update Query with limit cause SQLite

Tags: sqlite

i have table in SQLite named TBL_data

i have two fields id and name

All id is set to the -1

i want to update first occurrence of record

for this i have used

`update TBL_data set name = 'XYZ' where id = -1 limit 1`

it shows error, is there any other way ?

Comment: What is the significance of id ,if its not unique....try giving one,and also the where clause is useless in your case.

Comment: What is the error which you are getting?

Comment: this is just temporary records  which will identify new records with id = -1 all other records contains id with positive value,

Comment: A better schema design might be to have a separate table indicating which are temporary, or to have a boolean column indicating those which are temporary.  It's not good to reuse IDs.

Comment: A poor database design will result in poor application performances. And this will lead to a bad user experience.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

That query works only if you have compiled SQLite with `SQLITE_ENABLE_UPDATE_DELETE_LIMIT`.

If this is not the case, you have to use some unique key of your table to determine the rows:

```
UPDATE tbl_data
SET ...
WHERE rowid IN (SELECT rowid
                FROM tbl_data
                WHERE ...
                ORDER BY ...
                LIMIT 1)
```