# SQLiteDatabase update using replace function

Tags: android, sqlite, sqliteopenhelper

I want to use the SQLiteDatabase to perform an update using the SQLite `replace` function with a `LIMIT` where the SQL would amount to something like this:

```
UPDATE tbl SET tel = replace(tel, '0501', '0502') where tel in (SELECT tel FROM tbl WHERE tel LIKE '0501%' ORDER BY tel LIMIT 100);
```

This appears to be good SQL as in this [fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!7/acccd6/1).

So the signature of the update looks something like:

```
db.update(String table, ContentValues values, String whereClause, String[] whereArgs)
```

So I tried as a wild guess using `ContentValues` like:

```
ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
cv.put("tel","replace( tel, '0511', '0513' )");
int result = db.update(tableName,cv,whereClause,null);
```

and that doesn't execute the `REPLACE` function but takes it literally so.

So how to use the `REPLACE` function using the `update` is the question.

I need to know how many rows are affected.

EDIT: I changed the query to a valid SQLite syntax per comment link and now see it is valid but the `REPLACE` is not being evaluated.

Comment: It's not valid sql as understood by sqlite. You'll get the same error if you change to sqlite in sqlfiddle. What would you want to achieve with the `order by` and `limit`?

Comment: Perhaps this solution will help:: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29071169/update-query-with-limit-cause-sqlite

Comment: @laalto thanks - didn't see the sqlite in fiddle.  The `order by` was added so I could add the `limit` (seemed to be needed in syntax chart) - the limit is used so if I have 100,000 qualified records I only want to update a subset per statement.

Comment: @Barns thanks - i'd seen that one and was really hoping to use the `replace` function - but it does get me closer since now the question is now how get the replace function working in an `update`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The convenience methods do have limitations in regards to enclosing values.

You could instead utilise the `execSQL` method (see code re rawQuery) for example :-

```
public long alterRows(String from, String to, int limit) {
    long rv = 0;
    String[] args = new String[]{from,to,from,String.valueOf(limit)};
    String sql = "UPDATE " + TB_TBL +
            " SET " + COL_TBL_TEL + " = replace(" + COL_TBL_TEL + ",?,?) " + //<<<<IGNORE EXPRESSION EXPECTED
            " WHERE rowid IN (" +
            "SELECT rowid FROM " + TB_TBL +
            " WHERE " + COL_TBL_TEL + "=? " +
            "ORDER BY " + COL_TBL_TEL +
            " LIMIT ?" +
            ");" ;
    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
    db.execSQL(sql,args);
    //mDB.rawQuery(sqlxxx,args); //<<<< only does 1 update not 2
    //Ascertain the number of updates
    Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT changes()",null);
    if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
        rv = csr.getLong(0);
    }
    csr.close();
    Log.d("Updates","Number of updates = " + String.valueOf(rv)); //<<<< LOG number of updates
    return rv;
}
```

Which could be called like :-

```
    SO50378333DBHelper mDBHlpr = new SO50378333DBHelper(this);
    mDBHlpr.alterRows("0501","0502",2);
```

- Where `SO50378333DBHelper` is the DatabaseHelper (named as it is for my convenience) where the code above exists.

### Example used for testing

The following is the complete code used to test this.

First the DatabaseHelper **SO50378333DBHelper.java**

```
public class SO50378333DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public static final String DBNAME = "so50378333";
    public static final int DBVERSION = 1;
    public static final String TB_TBL = "tbl";
    public static final String COL_TBL_TEL = "tel";

    SQLiteDatabase mDB;

    public SO50378333DBHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DBNAME, null, DBVERSION);
        mDB = this.getWritableDatabase();

    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        String crt_tbl = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS " + TB_TBL +
                "(" +
                COL_TBL_TEL + " TEXT" +
                ")";
        db.execSQL(crt_tbl);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {

    }

    public void loadTBL() {
        ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
        mDB.beginTransaction();
        mDB.delete(TB_TBL,null,null);
        for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
            cv.clear();
            if ( i % 4 == 0) {
                cv.put(COL_TBL_TEL,"0501");
            } else {
                cv.put(COL_TBL_TEL,"0504");
            }
            mDB.insert(TB_TBL,null,cv);
        }
        String sql = "SELECT sqlite_version() AS v";
        Cursor csr = mDB.rawQuery(sql,null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            Log.d("SQLite VERSION","Version is " + csr.getString(0));
        }
        mDB.setTransactionSuccessful();
        mDB.endTransaction();

    }

    public long alterRows(String from, String to, int limit) {
        long rv = 0;
        String[] args = new String[]{from,to,from,String.valueOf(limit)};
        String sql = "UPDATE " + TB_TBL +
                " SET " + COL_TBL_TEL + " = replace(" + COL_TBL_TEL + ",?,?) " + //<<<<IGNORE EXPRESSION EXPECTED
                " WHERE rowid IN (" +
                "SELECT rowid FROM " + TB_TBL +
                " WHERE " + COL_TBL_TEL + "=? " +
                "ORDER BY " + COL_TBL_TEL +
                " LIMIT ?" +
                ");" ;
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        db.execSQL(sql,args);
        //mDB.rawQuery(sqlxxx,args); //<<<< only does 1 update not 2
        //Ascertain the number of updates
        Cursor csr = db.rawQuery("SELECT changes()",null);
        if (csr.moveToFirst()) {
            rv = csr.getLong(0);
        }
        csr.close();
        Log.d("Updates","Number of updates = " + String.valueOf(rv)); //<<<< LOG number of updates
        return rv;
    }
}
```

- See comments //<<<<
- `rawQuery` doesn't actually update any rows, even though the changes() function indicates that it has updated 1 instead of 2. This is likely because it is reporting on the last INSERT due to th rawQuery not performing any updates.
- `rawQuery` doesn't update as it's not until the result (the Cursor) is accessed (e.g. a moveToFirst()) (which it isn't) that it will do it's work.

Second the invoking code within an activity (**MainActivity.java**)

```
    SO50378333DBHelper mDBHlpr = new SO50378333DBHelper(this);
    mDBHlpr.loadTBL();
    mDBHlpr.alterRows("0501","0502",2);
```

- Note the call to `loadTBL` loads data into the table (deleting all rows before doing so). **1000** rows are inserted, every **first** row of **4** will be **"0501"** (250) all other rows (750) will be **"0504"**

Results in the Log from the above :-

> ```
> 05-16 23:19:31.554 2622-2622/? D/SQLite VERSION: Version is 3.7.11
> 05-16 23:19:31.558 2622-2622/? D/Updates: Number of updates = 2
> ```

Comment: Thanks for your efforts!  The `changes()` function is particularly helpful.